# How to Link SQL Server Express to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, connection-string, sql-server-express

Aimed to link my pages to an existing db from SQL Server Express. There are only one table is gonna select. Followed `NerdDinner` tutorial, using LINQ-to-SQL designer to do this.

However the result does not overcome what it suppose, my table `Dinner` can not be called directly, what would be the mistake I make?

The result return *.dbml and NerdDinner with *.edmx. What are their different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your connection string to store database in sql server express.Note that the *.edmx database type will store in local file system maybe at App-Data folder in your project as a database object. but another type, say, *.dbml is for using at DBMS system ,here SQL server Express. Also you can convert the *.edmx type to *.dbml type via SQL server tool.

Look at your web.config file at root of project.At the configurations, you will see that the connection string is setted to store at local file system of type .edmx. try to change it.

Comment: Does that mean app-data file in yellow folder color is the data stored locally and grey represent the extern linkage

Comment: The app-data folder will be used for storing data at local file system. Look at your Connection string at web.config file.It will decide where to store data.